# python27 requests.get() recursion

Tags: python, recursion, python-requests, infinite

I'm trying to get requests working. I'm just trying line one from the  documentation, here: 
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/ so I am assuming I have a bad install somehow?

Here is the example from the above:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))
```

I wouldn't think I'd get this kind of behavior from the first example provided in the docs.

I just get an infinite recursion from requests.get().

```
    File "C:\Python27\lib\requests.py", line 144, in get
        return requests.get(url, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\requests.py", line 144, in get
        return requests.get(url, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\requests.py", line 143, in get
    with ignore_insecure_warning(**kwargs):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
    return self.gen.next()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\requests.py", line 103, in ignore_insecure_warning
    with warnings.catch_warnings():
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

I wonder if somehow I have python or the libraries installed incorrectly because 
I'm also get errors related to pip

```
  pip install anythingAtAll
```

opens my Atom text editor with the tabs: "get-pip.py", "Install" & "anythingAtAll" but doesn't install.

If I uninstall atom, pip works fine.  I haven't seen these behaviors on other machines.  I tried a fresh install of python & atom that didn't resolve the pip errors.

Comment: Sounds like `pip` is tied to Atom to open files, not to the Python install tool.

Comment: `requests.py` is not the library that `python-requests.org` documents, because that is a *package*. Not sure what that really is instead.

Comment: Besides, I'd expect `requests` to live in `C:\Python27\lib\site-packages`, not in `C:\Python27\lib`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a different module named `requests.py`. It is calling itself repeatedly:

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\requests.py", line 144, in get
    return requests.get(url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\requests.py", line 144, in get
    return requests.get(url, **kwargs)
```

That's the `get()` function calling itself, eventually hitting the recursion limit with the context manager on the line before it.

Rename or delete that file, it is masking the real `requests` library (which uses a *package*, not a single module, so you'll see `requests/<something>.py` names in a traceback.

Comment: Yep, I reinstalled (again) and the superfluous requests.py was removed.  I may have accidentally install 2.7.0 rather than 2.7.14.  I'm not sure if 2.7.0 comes with requests?  Or if that was installed separately.   Thanks Martijn.

Comment: @DaveP: 2.7.0 does not come with a `requests.py` file, not in `lib`. See https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/v2.7/Lib